# nullPointerException when deploy webLogic 12c application

Tags: deployment, nullpointerexception, weblogic

when i deploy my first web app on webLogic i get this error:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:286)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:169)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:114)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:141)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:102)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Comment: nobody can help me please?

Comment: It sounds like the annotations in one of your classes is bad... hard to tell without seeing your servlet/service class and web.xml. Need more info for anyone to help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and resolved it by removing JSF 2.2 Mojarra 2.2.0 from the application libraries. It only needs to be in the classpath.

In Eclipse, edit properties for the project, go to Project Facets-->Java Server Faces and uncheck "Include libraries with this application" and Apply change.

Answer (score 0):

I deploy from Eclipse (OEPE), same problem here without JSF. Here is what solved my problem:

1. Quit Eclipse
2. Delete the workspace's .metadata folder
3. Launch Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

The same solution worked on NetBeans8. From projects, go to your war project, right click over Libraries > JSF2.2 and click Remove. Rebuild the project and deploy. Remember to deploy as shared library the JSF on WLS.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Maven generated ear file fails during deploying weblogic server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061963/maven-generated-ear-file-fails-during-deploying-weblogic-server/37847726#37847726).  Some details about the solution can be found in this post https://roundwheeltech.wordpress.com/2016/06/15/deploying-a-jsf-2-2-to-weblogic-12-1-3/.

Because WebLogic 12.1.3 ships with JSF 2.1, the required JSF jars have to be bundles within the WAR file (specified as dependencies in pom.xml).  WebLogic must also be instructed to use the libraries packaged in the WAR file instead of the ones that are provided by the container.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file web.xml and put:

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same NPE. It was started by an instantiation of an factory that went wrong. I had to remote debug in to find this. An exception in the initialisation of the factory is swallowed and we don't get the real exception.

In my case the problem was *antlr.Token* and *antlr.CommonToken* not arriving from the same source. This gave me an *ClassCastException*. I solved it by moving all libraries from the ear to war to get more control over them.