# WL12.2 processMultipartConfigAnnotation raises exception

Tags: jsf, weblogic12c, icefaces-3

I build WL12.2 with IceFace3.3.0GA_P07
and using jsf-api-2.2.20.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.28.0.jar, javax.servlet.jstl-1.2.jar on the classpath
now, I am getting a NullPointerException

```
<[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <4ca7b60a-acef-4505-94ce-91dd597eab38-00000009> <1599853451390> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] > <BEA-149205> <Failed to initialize the application "FTOLWeb" due to error weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException<br/>
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)<br/>
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)<br/>
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)<br/>
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionAppInternal(AppTransition.java:32)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused By: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessor.processMultipartConfigAnnotation(WebAnnotationProcessor.java:287)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationForClasses(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:201)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:145)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotationsOutsideWebFragment(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:173)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:130)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.AnnotationProcessingManager.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessingManager.java:105)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:2180)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.processAnnotations(WebAppModule.java:2142)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:814)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:295)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextStateInParallel(StateMachineDriver.java:144)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.parallelPrepare(ModuleStateDriver.java:46)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:75)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:55)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
        at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:241)
        at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.prepare(SingleModuleDeployment.java:52)
        at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:158)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:65)
        at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppDeployment.prepare(AppDeployment.java:166)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doPrepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:41)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.prepare(DeploymentAdapter.java:193)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$1.transitionAppInternal(AppTransition.java:32)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments$2.doItem(ConfiguredDeployments.java:741)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.parallel.BucketInvoker.invoke(BucketInvoker.java:138)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionAppsParallel(ConfiguredDeployments.java:749)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.prepare(ConfiguredDeployments.java:363)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:232)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:219)
        at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:133)
        at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.invoke(ReflectionHelper.java:1287)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:333)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:375)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:698)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:78)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:85)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2126)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:116)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1237)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1168)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:786)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:681)<br/>
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)<br/>
        at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)<br/>
        at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)<br/>
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)<br/>
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:655)<br/>
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)<br/>
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)<br/>
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this is of help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36835218/there-was-a-failure-when-processing-annotations-for-application

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer,
[nullPointerException when deploy webLogic 12c application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983947/nullpointerexception-when-deploy-weblogic-12c-application)
Namely, that I had the jsf2.2.jar once in WEB-INF/lib dir and once in the classpath.  I removed it from WEB-INF/lib!

Back to my original problem
[WL12.2 upgrade gives timeout on database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63801434/wl12-2-upgrade-gives-timeout-on-database)
which seems to be giving me
"HTML parsing or JS evaluation error [code: 200]: element.getAttribute is not a function" on console